# PHP visualization library for Google Charts API

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm implementing some Google charts using PHP as the backend. Unfortunately of the PHP visualization implementations I've found, the best looked like Mailchimp's MC-goog-visualization (http://code.google.com/p/mc-goog-visualization/issues/detail?id=13).

This allows you to create a Google data source from a mysql DB with minimal coding. The downside is, the project is not actively developed and has many bugs (including showstoppers like "WHERE" clauses and scalars don't appear to work right.

Can anyone who's worked with PHP/mysql and Google Charts recommend a data source wrapper that actually works with the Google query formats?

Thanks

Comment: I am using Google's Visualization API, and I have found it best to implement by own wrapper.  That way, I can include custom formatted versions of data, and avoid security issues with client-side generated queries.

Comment: thanks Brad-- you're probably right. Well, there's three days wasted trying to get the mailchimp stuff working properly! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found [bggardner/google-visualization-php](https://github.com/bggardner/google-visualization-php), looks active, but I didn't try it.